# What does $\max_{i,j} \langle\phi_{i}, \psi_{j}\rangle$ mean in mathematics?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

I was reading through a research paper on compressive sensing, and I came across the following:

Let $z \in d_{z}$ denote a vectorized image with $d_{z}$ pixels. Assume
that $z$ is $K$–sparse in a basis given by the columns of $\Psi \in \Re^{d_{z} \times d_{z}}$,
meaning that $z = Ψθ$  and at most $K$ of the coordinates of $θ$ are
nonzero. Compressive sensing theory ensures that $\theta$, and therefore
$z$, can with high probability be exactly recovered from appropriate
linear projections onto the rows of a measurement matrix
$\phi \in \Re^{d_{y}×d_{z}}$ , with $d_{y} < d_{z}$. Specifically, define the $coherence$ $\mu$
between $\phi$ and $\psi$ as $\mu \equiv
\sqrt{d_{z}} \max_{i,j} \langle\phi_{i}, \psi_{j}\rangle \in [1, \sqrt{d_{z}}]$
for all
rows $\phi_{i}$ and columns $\psi_{j}$ of $\phi$ and $\psi$, respectively;

What is the meaning of the equation $μ ≡
\sqrt{d_{z}} \max_{i,j} <\phi_{i}, \psi_{j}> \in [1, \sqrt{d_{z}}]$ in the above context?

Also, is $\mu$ a scalar value or a vector?

Comment: It seems to denote a matrix... I think that $\phi_i$ is a value of the Vector $\Phi$ and the same for $\psi_j$. They are number; thus their max is a number.

Comment: $d_z$ seems to be a number (see "with $d_z$ pixels" and see the interval $[1, \sqrt {d_z}]$). and thus $\mu$ must be a number

Comment: $ϕ_{i}$, $ψ_{j}$ are row and colum vectors respectively, so what do we get after applying the max operation on these two vectors?

Comment: Agreed, $μ$ will be a number as it will lie in the interval $[1,\sqrt{d_{z}}] $, but how is the max operation working on two input vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct the matrix whose ij entry is $\phi_i \cdot \psi_j$. Then take the maximum entry of that matrix. This gives a scalar. Multiplying by the other scalar $\sqrt{d_z}$ gives another scalar for $\mu$. The angle brackets for the dot product seems to have been the source of your confusion.

Comment: yes, the angular brackets were confusing me. Thank you for answering my query!

Comment: Can you please explain to me, the meaning of the phrase: "linear projections onto the rows of a measurement matrix" in the above context? I looked it up online, but I am not able to find any relevant resource, it might also help me if you could suggest appropriate search term for it...